# HTS Prophet Holidays Issue

Tags: python, facebook-prophet

I am attempting to use the htsprophet package in Python. I am using the following example code below. This example is pulled from https://github.com/CollinRooney12/htsprophet/blob/master/htsprophet/runHTS.py . The issue I am getting is ValueError `"holidays must be a DataFrame with 'ds' and 'holiday' column`. I am wondering if there is a work around this because I clearly have a data frame holidays with the two columns ds and holidays. I believe that the error comes from one of the dependency packages from fbprophet from the forecaster file. I am wondering if there is anything that I need to add or if anyone has added something to fix this.

```
import pandas as pd
from htsprophet.hts import hts, orderHier, makeWeekly
from htsprophet.htsPlot import plotNode, plotChild, plotNodeComponents
import numpy as np

#%% Random data (Change this to whatever data you want)
date = pd.date_range("2015-04-02", "2017-07-17")
date = np.repeat(date, 10)
medium = ["Air", "Land", "Sea"]
businessMarket = ["Birmingham","Auburn","Evanston"]
platform = ["Stone Tablet","Car Phone"]
mediumDat = np.random.choice(medium, len(date))
busDat = np.random.choice(businessMarket, len(date))
platDat = np.random.choice(platform, len(date))
sessions = np.random.randint(1000,10000,size=(len(date),1))
data = pd.DataFrame(date, columns = ["day"])
data["medium"] = mediumDat
data["platform"] = platDat
data["businessMarket"] = busDat
data["sessions"] = sessions

#%% Run HTS
##
# Make the daily data weekly (optional)
##
data1 = makeWeekly(data)
##
# Put the data in the format to run HTS, and get the nodes input (a list of list that describes the hierarchical structure)
##
data2, nodes = orderHier(data, 1, 2, 3)
##
# load in prophet inputs (Running HTS runs prophet, so all inputs should be gathered beforehand)
# Made up holiday data
##
holidates = pd.date_range("12/25/2013","12/31/2017", freq = 'A')
holidays = pd.DataFrame(["Christmas"]*5, columns = ["holiday"])
holidays["ds"] = holidates
holidays["lower_window"] = [-4]*5
holidays["upper_window"] = [0]*5
##
# Run hts with the CVselect function (this decides which hierarchical aggregation method to use based on minimum mean Mean Absolute Scaled Error)
# h (which is 12 here) - how many steps ahead you would like to forecast.  If youre using daily data you don't have to specify freq.
#
# NOTE: CVselect takes a while, so if you want results in minutes instead of half-hours pick a different method
##
myDict = hts(data2, 52, nodes, holidays = holidays, method = "FP", transform = "BoxCox")
##
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the htsProphet package, with the 'fitForecast.py' file. The instantiation of the fbProphet object relies on just positional arguments, however a new argument as been added to the fbProphet class. This means the arguments don't correspond anymore.

You can solve this by hacking the fbProphet module and changing the positional arguments to keyword arguments, just fixing lines '73-74' should be sufficient to get it running:

```
Prophet(growth=growth, changepoints=changepoints1, n_changepoints=n_changepoints1, yearly_seasonality=yearly_seasonality, weekly_seasonality=weekly_seasonality, holidays=holidays, seasonality_prior_scale=seasonality_prior_scale, \
                            holidays_prior_scale=holidays_prior_scale, changepoint_prior_scale=changepoint_prior_scale, mcmc_samples=mcmc_samples, interval_width=interval_width, uncertainty_samples=uncertainty_samples)
```

Ill submit a bug for this to the creators.